# Can I see when a change was merged into my git branch?

Tags: git

When I open 'gitk [filename]', I can see when a change was committed, but is it also possible to know since when it was included in your branch?

Answer (score 0):

I may know how to do this from the command line. The command `git log` shows basic info for each commit, like the commit id, the author, the commit date and description. With `git log --merges` or `git log --min-parents=2` you will see only the merge commits, therefore you will be able to check when the merge happened.
Checkout [git-log](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around to find something similar - get the timestamp of when a change was pulled/merged into your local branch. And this is what I found is useful:

Command:
`git reflog show --date=default`

Output:

`5c4f140 HEAD@{Mon Aug 10 05:36:24 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
1ba6e4e HEAD@{Wed Aug 5 14:40:50 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
05382e4 HEAD@{Wed Jul 22 12:27:20 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
bad194c HEAD@{Wed Jul 22 09:54:01 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
016f6cb HEAD@{Sat Jul 18 04:53:56 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward
b4839d3 HEAD@{Mon Jul 6 07:35:23 2015 +0000}: pull origin: Fast-forward`